# Get Related Data from ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python, django

Working with ManyToManyField I want to get data of all the users related to all the queried model object along with other field data in the model.

For example for the below model, I have 2 users related to this "ChatRoom"

```
class ChatRoomParticipants(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='chatroom_users')
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

With the below query

```
chatrooms = list(ChatRoomParticipants.objects.filter(user=user).values('user__user_uid', 'room__id', 'room__name'))
```

I'm able to fetch

```
[{'user__user_uid': UUID('f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610'), 'room__id': 4, 'room__name': 'f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610-872952bb-6c34-4e50-b6fd-7053dfa583de'}]
```

But I'm expecting something like

```
[{
'user__user_uid1': UUID('f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610'),
'user__user_uid2': UUID('872952bb-6c34-4e50-b6fd-7053dfa583de'), 
'room__id': 4, 
'room__name': 'f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610-872952bb-6c34-4e50-b6fd-7053dfa583de'
},
{
'user__user_uid1': UUID('f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610'),
'user__user_uid2': UUID('eecd66e7-4874-4b96-bde0-7dd37d0b83b3'),
'room__id': 5, 
'room__name': 'f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610-eecd66e7-4874-4b96-bde0-7dd37d0b83b3'
},
{
'user__user_uid1': UUID('f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610'),
'user__user_uid2': UUID('4f4c0f3d-2292-4d06-afdc-1e95962ac5e6'),
'room__id': 6, 
'room__name': 'f4253fbd-90d1-471f-b541-80813b51d610-4f4c0f3d-2292-4d06-afdc-1e95962ac5e6'
}]
```

I've searched and found I can do something like

```
user_data = chatrooms.users.all().values('user_uid')
```

But the above doesn't work well with `filter` and I would miss out data on `room`.

Note: I know that's not a correct method to do what I'm trying to achieve, if anyone can enlighten with what's the correct way to achieve the same data.

Answer (score 0):

your example is somewhat confusing, but I think what you are looking for is to find the information of the users related to the same room.

```
chat_room = ChatRoomParticipants.objects.get(id=id_room)
users_chat = chat_room.user.all().values_list('user_uid', flat=True)
data = {
    "room__id": chat_room.room.id
    "room__name": chat_room.room.name
    "users" : users_chat
}
```

for something more consistent you can use serializers

Comment: I've updated expected answer for better understanding. I hope now it makes it less confusing.